# swiper thumbs only from specific breakpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, swiper.js

I want to show swiper thumbs only from 768px dimension and after 1200px I want to show vertical thumbs. I don't understand why thumbs are showing under 768px if thumbs start at this breakpoint.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var swiper_product_full_gallery_thumb = new Swiper("#product-full-gallery-thumb-vertical", {
            spaceBetween: 10,
            slidesPerView: 5,
            lazy: true,
            watchSlidesProgress: true,
            watchOverflow: true,
            watchSlidesVisibility: true,
            direction: "horizontal",
            breakpoints: {
                1200: {
                    direction: "vertical",
                    slidesPerView: 4
                }
           }
        });
        var swiper_product_full_gallery = new Swiper("#product-full-gallery-vertical", {
            lazy: true,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            navigation: {
                nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
                prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
            },
            breakpoints: {
                768: {
                    thumbs: {
                        swiper:swiper_product_full_gallery_thumb,
                    },
                }
            }
            
        });

    });
```